# Resistances connected in series

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

When resistances connected in series then why through each resistances the different potential difference occurs?

Comment: Because the current has no choice but to flow through each and every resistor which causes a potential difference across each one.

Comment: Since they're in series the current through them is equal (there's nowhere else for the current to go). But  Ohm's Law says V=IR, so if they have different R values, there will be different potential differences (V).

Answer (score 0):

No, potential difference across each resistor need not be different always. In series, you should remember that potential difference across any resistor is proportional to its resistance. In other words, potential difference can be same across each resistor if each resistors value is same.
[image]
If resistance values are different, say $R_1$ and $R_2$, then by ohms law $V_1=IR_1$, $V_2=IR_2$, both are different.

Answer (score 0):

You must remember that ***current in series combination is constant throughout the circuit***. But the resistance of resistor can be different, so if there are two resistors with same resistance value, the amount of potential difference is also the the same in the resistors. But ***if resistance varies***, then ***according to ohm's law***, potential difference is also different.